# Подключение по логину и паролю пользователя БД MS SQL в С# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане.
Вопрос и проблема состоит в следующем. Нужно написать небольшую Субд - клиента для базовых действий над базой данных. Использую C# WindowsForms и фреймворк EntityFramework. Сначала была создана база данных (она рабочая), потом при помощи фреймворка создал модель базы данных в приложении на C# по принципу DataBaseFirst. Всё подключалось , работало и выводило из БД на формы нормально. Но по заданию необходимо подключаться к БД через логин и пароль пользователей определённых ролей в БД. Тут и возникла проблема. Перечитал и перепробовал многие варианты из уже имеющихся на форумах и сайтах, но ничего не помогает.
Не знаю, что именно показать на форуме, но вот несколько фрагментов:

Сгенерированная строка для подключения к БД (при помощи неё всё ок)

Переопределил конструктор контекста БД, для передачи ему своей строки подключения

```
public partial class ChildGartenDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public ChildGartenDBContext()
            : base("name=ChildGartenDBContext")
        {
        }
        public ChildGartenDBContext(string dbConnectionString)
           : base(dbConnectionString)
        {
        }
```

Собственно попытки передачи строки и установления в дальнейшем подключения:

```
string str = "Server=HOMEPC;Database=ChildGartenDB;Trusted_Connection=true";
            string connectionString = @"metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=HOMEPC;initial catalog=ChildGartenDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;";
            DBContext = new ChildGartenDBContext(str);
```

Если использую первую строку , то выдает ошибку :

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The context is being used in Code First mode
>   with code that was generated from an EDMX file

Если использую вторую строку, то выдает ошибку:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'data source'.

В конечном итоге, нужно получать из формы логин и пароль пользователя, создавать строку подключения и собственно подключаться к БД.
Думаю, это очень распространенная задача и проблема.
Благодарю за любую помощь и ответы!

Answer (score -1):

По задаче тебе нужно заменить **Trusted_Connection** на **User id** \ **Password** как в примере ниже:

```
 string str = "Server=HOMEPC;Database=ChildGartenDB;User id=UserName;Password=*****;";
 string connectionString = @"metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=HOMEPC;initial catalog=ChildGartenDB;User id=UserName;Password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;";
 DBContext = new ChildGartenDBContext(connectionString);
```

Больше почитать об стрках подключения можешь к [примеру здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax)

Твоё исключение говорит о том, что вместо простого подключения ты решил использовать EF с подходом CodeFirst. Чтобы не падало это исключение тебе необходимо его отключить. Как сделать это можешь [почитать здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41664009/3218447)
В том ответе предлагается сделать следующее:

1. Удалить текущую строку подключения из **web.config**
2. Найти .edmx файл в проекте и дважді кликнув открыть его увидев чтото типо этого:
   [image: edmx-model]
3. Если вы кликните по "Update Model From database..." вы увидите:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   Убедитесь что вы поставили галку "Save connection setting in App.Config as"
4. После этого если ваш **.edmx** не находится в главнвом проекте а в других сборках Вам необходимо скопировать *connection string* в главный проект.

P.S. Скажите спасибо автору ответа на англоязыном стеке.

Comment: Благодарю за Ваш ответ, но не помог. В нем говорится о том, что делать, если в принципе не подключается к БД. Т.е. пересоздается автоматическое подключение с автоматически созданной строкой подключения. У меня с этим проблем не было. Мне же необходимо как-то передавать для подключения свою строку , которую я формирую во время выполнения программы.

Comment: @Vladyslav_ Я правильно понял, ваш вопрос заключается в том как подключится при помощи строки собранной вами ?

Comment: @Vladyslav_ я в ответе раскрыл как можно решить проблему с исключением и как сформировать строку для подключения по логину\паролю. Пожалуйста, сделайте вопрос более конкретным.

Comment: Да, строка создаётся в App.config, мне же необходимо запрашивать логин и пароль с формы, потом формировать строку подключения и работать с этим подключением до конца выполнения программы.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что приложение "хочет" работать исключительно со строкой, которую оно сформировало при создании модели бд из готовой бд на сервере. И любая попытка подключится по-другому, вызывает исключение.

Comment: @Vladyslav_ Почти невозможно ответить на общий вопрос. Если Ваша проблема в формировании строки подключения, почитайте о [формирователях строк подключения](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms254947(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Я не могу понять, как ещё точнее объяснить суть проблемы. Как формировать строку я понял , что-то на подобии "Data Source=homepc;Initial Catalog=ChildGartenDB;User ID=db_admin;Password=admin". Но такое подключение не работает, а выдаёт ошибку, о решении которой Вы сбросили статью. Но в статье удаляется нерабочая строка подключения, после чего программа автоматически генерирует новую, т.е. в том ответе решалась проблема в принципе нерабочей строки, а не то, как использовать свою.

Comment: Если у вас будет рабочая строка подключения, то в ней вы можете сами задать имя пользователя и пароль в рантайме. Вы можете даже захардкодить как строку для форматирования и в коде вызвав string.Format(connectionString, userName, password) и передать это в конструктор контекста.

Comment: Да, Вы где-то правильно понимаете суть вопроса. Но как это сделать? Сначала нужно создать конструктор контекста, который бы мог получать параметром строку. Потом в коде создавать строку, примерно так:  string con1 = "Data Source=homepc;Initial Catalog=ChildGartenDB;User ID=db_admin;Password=admin";
            DBContext = new ChildGartenDBContext(con1);
И после этого всё должно работать нормально? Или я чего-то не учитываю/не понимаю?

Comment: @Vladyslav_ давсё верно но учтите пару моментов. Такой конструктор у Вас уже есть. Именно тот который принимает имя строки подключения может кроме имени принимать и строку подключения. Вполне возможно что строка будет выглядеть немного не так, и должна будет включать ещё и метаописание модели, при этом будет выглядеть как то так: "metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=PC;initial catalog=DB;User id=UserName;Password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;";

Comment: Я правда, очень благодарен за Ваши ответы и потраченное время, но так и не могу понять, как же всё-таки это сделать. У вас есть пример создания и использования своей строки для подключения?
Ведь у меня есть только такой конструктор : public ChildGartenDBContext()
            : base("name=ChildGartenDBContext") {  }
в который нельзя передать свою строку.
И строка должна быть сформирована при помощи каких-то специальных инструментов, или как обычная строка?

Comment: Но чуть ниже у вас уже есть такой конструктор **public ChildGartenDBContext(string dbConnectionString) : base(dbConnectionString) { }**

Comment: Я его сам создал и когда я обновляю модель, он удаляется

Comment: И возможно, из-за этого в том числе выбрасывается исключение

Comment: Ваш класс **partial** в другом файле объявите вторую часть _partial_ класса.